# cant create table in Mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create table in Mysql database with the below sql

```
   CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dev_dict`.`TAMILWORD_SECONDARY` (
    `ID` INT NOT NULL ,
    `TAMILWORD_ID` INT NOT NULL ,
    `WORDS` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
    `CREATED_DTTM` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
    `MODIFIED_DTTM` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
     PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
       UNIQUE INDEX `WORDS_UNIQUE` (`WORDS` ASC, `TAMILWORD_ID` ASC) ,
       INDEX `FK_TAMILWORD_ID_idx` (`TAMILWORD_ID` ASC) ,
     CONSTRAINT `FK_TAMILWORD_ID`
       FOREIGN KEY (`TAMILWORD_ID` )
       REFERENCES `dev_dict`.`TAMILWORD` (`ID` )
       ON DELETE NO ACTION
     ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

but getting Error Code: 1022. Can't write; duplicate key in table 'tamilword_secondary'.

thanks for helping me.. i have the table tamilword already , and getting same error

```
   CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dev_dict`.`TAMILWORD` (
     `ID` INT NOT NULL ,
     `WORD` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NOT NULL ,
     `SENTENCE` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
     `CREATED_DTTM` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
    `MODIFIED_DTTM` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
     PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
        INDEX `SECONDARY` (`WORD` ASC, `SENTENCE` ASC) )
     ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: i can create table if i change engine to MyISAM. i dont know about database engine.. and other tables has engine as InnoDB. please let me know is this correct way?.

Answer (score 0):

Create `dev_dict.TAMILWORD` table first.
Other than that your statement works.

**See [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20a7f)**